# How can this property of definite integrals be true?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397806/int-pi-2-0-log-sin-x-dx-int-pi-2-0-log-cos-x-dx/397848#397848), people are saying that the definite integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $a$ is equal to the integral of $f(a-x)$ from $0$ to $a$. How can that be true? Simple examples don't work.

Comment: What simple example do you have in mind?

Comment: If you post a "simple example" which doesn't work, then we can probably see exactly where you're going wrong, and give a much more helpful answer!

Comment: The area below a curve is the same if you reflect the curve in a vertical line...

Comment: Well take for example f(x)=x. The integral from 0 to 5 is 25/2. Now take f(x-2.5)=x-2.5. The integral of this from 0 to 5 is equal to 0.

Comment: Well, you're not following your own rules. You have to look at $f(5-x)$ !!

Comment: Oh wow haha I must've been dreaming when I wrote this question, I completely didn't take into account that the a in a-x is the same as the a in the limit of integration, I thought a was just any arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $z=a-x$ then $dz=-dx$. When $x=0, z=a$ and when $x=a,z=0$. Now $$\int_0^af(a-x)dx=\int_a^0f(z)(-dz)=\int_0^af(z)dz$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$g(x):=f(a-x)\qquad(0\leq x\leq a)\ .$$
It follows that
$$g\left({a\over2}+y\right)=f\left({a\over2}-y\right) \qquad\left(-{a\over2}\leq y\leq{a\over2}\right)\ .$$
Therefore the graph of $g$ is the graph of $f$, reflected at the vertical $x={a\over2}$. Assuming for simplicity that $f$, and therefore $g$, are $\geq0$, it is obvious that the areas $A_f$ and $A_g$ in question are the same.